# How to fix [-Wreturn-type] error in mac OS

Tags: c

I have programmed a scheduler on one compiler.  When I compile on Debian 9 Linux, all is ok, but when I try to compile on my Mac running macOS, then it shows a lot of warnings and this error:

```
error: non-void function 'CloseForLoops' should return a value [-Wreturn-type] return;
```

The method that shows the error:

```c
CloseForLoops (pp,i)
PATTERN *pp;
int i;
{
    int j;

    if (pp == (PATTERN *) NULL)
        return;
        if (pp->p_expression->e_tag == T_IDENTIFIER)
    {
        CloseForLoops (pp->p_next, ++i);
        fprintf (Output, "UNLOCK_NODE(ptr_%d->rtb_tag);\n}\n", i-1);
        } else {
                register PATTERN *pt = pp->p_expression->e_val.e_pattern;

        j = i++;
                while (pt != (PATTERN *) NULL)
                {
            if ((pt = pt->p_next) != (PATTERN *) NULL)
                i++;
                }
        CloseForLoops (pp->p_next, ++i);
        fprintf (Output, "UNLOCK_NODE(ptr_%d->rtb_tag);\n}\n", j);
        }

}   /* end CloseForLoops */
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Please show a minimal example of your code.

Comment: What *type* is the `CloseForLoops` function supposed to return? Hint: if you write a function like `size_t foo(int bar) { /* etc */ }`, then every branch in that function must return `size_t`.

Comment: That code is ancient and should be modernized. For starters, change its return type to `void` in its definition and in all its declarations. Maybe nobody uses a return value from it.

Comment: If you used GCC 5 or later, your code would not compile without warnings.  You're using C90 (or pre-standard) code, and that type of 'implicit int' declaration is no longer acceptable in standard C, and GCC 5 and later default to C11 as the standard, whereas GCC 4 or earlier defaults to C90 as the standard.  Do use modern compilers.  Don't use archaic coding conventions.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't provide a return type in C, a return type of `int` is assumed.  In other words,

```c
CloseForLoops (pp,i)
PATTERN *pp;
int i;
```

Is equivalent to

```c
int CloseForLoops (pp,i)
PATTERN *pp;
int i;
```

Or, with a modern (circa 1989) syntax:

```c
int CloseForLoops (PATTERN *pp, int i) { ... }
```

The problem is that you never actually return a value in the function body.  There is a `return` statement without a value, and control reaches the end of the function without returning a value.

You have two choices… either keep the current return type unaltered and return values:

```c
CloseForLoops (pp,i)
PATTERN *pp;
int i;
{
    int j;

    if (pp == (PATTERN *) NULL)
        return 0;
        if (pp->p_expression->e_tag == T_IDENTIFIER)
    {
        CloseForLoops (pp->p_next, ++i);
        fprintf (Output, "UNLOCK_NODE(ptr_%d->rtb_tag);\n}\n", i-1);
        } else {
                register PATTERN *pt = pp->p_expression->e_val.e_pattern;

        j = i++;
                while (pt != (PATTERN *) NULL)
                {
            if ((pt = pt->p_next) != (PATTERN *) NULL)
                i++;
                }
        CloseForLoops (pp->p_next, ++i);
        fprintf (Output, "UNLOCK_NODE(ptr_%d->rtb_tag);\n}\n", j);
        }
        return 0;
}   /* end CloseForLoops */
```

Or change function so it doesn't return a value:

```c
void CloseForLoops (pp,i)
PATTERN *pp;
int i;
{
    int j;

    if (pp == (PATTERN *) NULL)
        return;
        if (pp->p_expression->e_tag == T_IDENTIFIER)
    {
        CloseForLoops (pp->p_next, ++i);
        fprintf (Output, "UNLOCK_NODE(ptr_%d->rtb_tag);\n}\n", i-1);
        } else {
                register PATTERN *pt = pp->p_expression->e_val.e_pattern;

        j = i++;
                while (pt != (PATTERN *) NULL)
                {
            if ((pt = pt->p_next) != (PATTERN *) NULL)
                i++;
                }
        CloseForLoops (pp->p_next, ++i);
        fprintf (Output, "UNLOCK_NODE(ptr_%d->rtb_tag);\n}\n", j);
        }

}   /* end CloseForLoops */
```

The reason it works on some compilers and not others is that **technically** this is valid code.  It's just so terrible that compilers will often warn you about it, and apparently on OS X this warning has been elevated to an error by default.  You can disable this by passing `-Wno-return-type` to the compiler, which asks it to ignore this particular issue, but this is a very very bad practice to get into.

It's a good thing they have this enabled, it's catching a real problem.  There is a good chance that those other warnings are legitimate as well; you should look into them, and *enable warnings on your compiler* as well (try passing `-Wall`, or `-Wreturn-type` to warn about this specific issue, or `-Werror=return-type` to make this issue an error).  Even better, you can treat all warnings as errors by passing `-Werror`, and once you fix them all your code quality will have improved significantly.

Comment: Try it with `-Wall`.  Compilers enable different warnings by default.  Best practice is basically to enable as many as you can, treat them as errors (to force you to fix them), and if possible test your code on multiple compilers to get the benefit of all the different warnings.

Comment: but code run ok in Debian and the signature the method is CloseForLoops (pp,i), this code did not go developed for me, just I get him to develop scheduler for my master graduate, sorry my English not is my native language!

Comment: nemequ don't resolve with -Wall, show the same error!

Comment: The problem isn't the arguments, it's the return value.  `return;` vs. `return X;`.  `-Wall` is to enable the warning on your compiler as well, not to ignore it.  To ignore it you would use `-Wno-return-type`, but that doesn't **fix** the problem, it just hides the warning.

Comment: i'm not know that argument return because in the debain work it

Comment: Did you mean to omit the `int` return type in the revised code?

Comment: @JuniorFernandes: You'll be using GCC.  Even GCC 4.x supports the basic warning options like `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` — and you should add `-Wmissing-prototypes` and `-Wstrict-prototypes` and (if your GCC supports them and doesn't enable them with the other options, `-Wold-style-declarations -Wold-style-definitions`).  There are other options you could add, but those will head off problems.  The mere fact that code compiles and runs on one type of machine does not mean it will compile, let alone run, on other types of machines.  And using archaic notations doesn't help your cause.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes.  I was a bit conflicted about it, but I thought leaving it alone but making the return statements return an int might help to more clearly explain what was happening with the implicit int return type. His English obviously isn't very strong (I mean no offense, it's better than any of my foreign languages), so anything I can do to drive that point home…

Comment: If you add the return type, the code _is_ (almost) valid C99 (C11, C18), albeit not entirely desirable because it is not using prototype notation (the notation used is obsolescent).  If you omit the return type, the code is not valid C99.   The 'almost' is because there is a `return;` in the body which isn't valid in a function returning an `int` — it needs to be `return 0;` or similar, as in your revision.  That suggests that it would be better to use the `void` return type; the callers are not expected to look at the return value.  The function should be declared (with prototype) before use.